# Android: Toolbar Back Button Is Transparent

Tags: java, android, android-toolbar

I Added a back button to a activity's toolbar but it looks transparent for some reason.

```
toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
    toolbar.setNavigationIcon(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_toolbar_back));
    toolbar.getNavigationIcon().setColorFilter(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorTitleText), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
    toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            finish();
        }
    });
```

Notes:
Language is Java.

```
android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar

android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that the problem was not caused by my code, it was caused by Android Studio's weird Image Asset creation. While creating a image asset type toolbar icon Android Studio changes the image's alpha.

My solution is using [this site](https://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/) and adding assets manualy.

Answer (score 0):

Try using ContextCompat() to get color like this below code.

```
 toolbar.navigationIcon?.setColorFilter(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.white),
                PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP)
```

Comment: I changed getResources to ContextCompat for getting the color but it still gives me the same result. I changed getNavigationIcon to navigationIcon? and it gave me an error.

Comment: this code is in kotlin. U just need to change context compat

Comment: I think I understood what is the problem. While I creating the Image Asset Android Studio makes images transparent. I don't know why and how to fix it and I couldn't find help online. Still searching for it.

Comment: Did you use Actionbar theme in your style.xml or NoActionBar theme?

Comment: NoActionBar. What does it affect?

Comment: It means there will be no default actionbar. Did you use custom toolbar to show toolbar in your app?

Comment: If you mean setSupportActionBar, yes. If don't I don't know because I new to Android.